# htaccess redirect without the path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess rule:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.co.uk/blog/
```

On an old blog at `http://blog.example.co.uk/` that should be redirecting ALL urls from this old blog to the new one.

However if I have anything in the path: e.g. `http://blog.example.co.uk/2015/test-post` then it redirects to `http://www.example.co.uk/blog/2015/test-post`

How do I make it so that it doesn't keep the path and just redirects to the domain.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use `RedirectMatch` for that:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^ http://www.example.co.uk/blog/
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser.

Or if you want to strip off any existing query string also then use `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.co.uk/blog/? [L,R=301]
```